# Use MYSQL data via PHP in cocoa-touch?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've created a working app for the iPhone which grabs data from a MYSQL database via a PHP page, then prints the data in a UIWebView.

But the issue here is that I no longer want to print the data in a UIWebView, I want to retrieve the data and pull it back into the app, to change a UILabel.text to the MYSQL data.

I currently have the following (which prints the data into a UIWebView (excluding most code due to DB connection passwords etc)):

**PHP FILE:**

```
    // Localize the GET variables
    $name   = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name']  : "";

    // Protect against sql injections
    $name  = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    $cash = "SELECT cash FROM t_users WHERE username='$name' LIMIT 1";


    $result = mysql_query($cash,$conn);

    if(!$result) {
        die("Error retrieving scores " . mysql_error());
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // Display the table
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                echo ''.$row->cash.'';
        }

            mysql_free_result($result);
            mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PlayerInfo.m**

```
-(IBAction)refreshData:(id)sender {

test1AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (test1AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSString * login_key = @"REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW";
NSString * username = [mainDelegate.currentUser stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW/put_score.php?login_key=%@&name=%@",
                       login_key,username];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

This changes shows the players CASH in the webview, but I want to change a UILabel to display the cash figure.

Please help?

Thank you!

Comment: It is possible... check out my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the text of the label to the value of row->cash:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:row-cas];
```

or you might need the `stringWithCString:encoding:` class method on the NSString class.

Comment: This doesn't even work as pseudocode :P No but seriously, you need to take a look a json or xml. There's no other good way to transfer data between app<->backend.

Comment: can you not access the value of row->cash? is it not a c-string. sorry... I intended this more as a question.. should have left a comment really

Comment: yes, you can do this... you use NSMutableURLRequest with the address for your PHP file - as you have been doing already. then, create a NSURLConnection with that request and name a delegate for the NSURLConnection. the delegate will receive messages as the connection progresses, such as connection:didReceiveData:. then, you can use the above code to draw the string text to a label.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the PHP script return JSON or simply just return the string you're interested in. Preferably JSON. Google "REST API", because that's what you really want.

A few good libraries to recommend are:

- JSONKit
- ASIHTTPRequest

Google will help you find those as well.